# How to monitor the status of scrapy while running

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I want to know what is going on while scrapy is running , how can i monitor the status ?

Answer (score 3):

There are two methods. The first method, here is a example from the official document.

```
telnet localhost 6023
>>> est()
Execution engine status
time()-engine.start_time : 8.62972998619
engine.has_capacity() :         False
len(engine.downloader.active) :         16
engine.scraper.is_idle() :      False
engine.spider.name :        followall
engine.spider_is_idle(engine.spider) :      False
engine.slot.closing :       False
len(engine.slot.inprogress) :       16
len(engine.slot.scheduler.dqs or []) :      0
len(engine.slot.scheduler.mqs) :        92
len(engine.scraper.slot.queue) :        0
len(engine.scraper.slot.active) :       0
engine.scraper.slot.active_size :       0
engine.scraper.slot.itemproc_size :         0
engine.scraper.slot.needs_backout() :   False
```

For more information, please refer to the official document.

The second method seems a little simpler. You can get get the status of crawler through the following method:

```
    self.crawler.stats.get_stats() 
or 
    spider.crawler.stats.get_stats()
```

So, just print out the status as you like.

Comment: thanks. There is "web service" from the official document , do you know  how to enable it ?

Comment: It is enabled by default. But if you are not sure, you can explicitly enable by setting WEBSERVICE_ENABLED = True

Answer (score 0):

There is also a third party extension to monitor the scrapy status

- [scrapy-jsonrpc](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-jsonrpc)

This project was built in scrapy once, now it's independent.
scrapy-jsonrc control and monitor a running Scrapy web crawler via JSON-RPC and has a web service.

[web-service](http://scrapy-chs.readthedocs.io/zh_CN/0.24/topics/webservice.html) in scrapy documents of old version.

- [scrapy monitor](https://github.com/ioiogoo/scrapy-monitor)

This project use a StatcollectorMiddleware to store stats of current requests to redis. And have a web service as well.